# Gauss's law problem. ( Need someone to point me in the right direction)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> *What force per square meter pushes 2 infinite planes charged positively when their charge density is $0.3 \, \mu C/\mathrm{m}^2$*

---

> *Second part is - using Gauss's theorem derive the equation for electric field current between infinite electrified planes.*

---

Hi everyone, just need some general direction to how to start solving problems like these. I want to understand the task more then get the right answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Electric Field Between Two Parallel Infinite Plates of Positive Charge and a Gaussian Cylinder](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79446/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to draw a Gaussian surface. In this case, you can use a rectangular box and look at the electric flux out the top and bottom of the surface of that Gaussian box. The usefulness of Gauss's is that it exploits symmetry in the problem allowing you to treat the electric field as a constant when you take the surface integral of E dot da. Which equals Q enclosed divided by epsillion.